# Text appears that's not in code

Tags: c#, forms, text, richtextbox, windows-forms-designer

I'm making a game. In this game there is a lot of dialogue. So, the text property of my `richTextBox1` is constantly changing. At first I had it set to say "What should I do?" and "Now what?" but I took that out because I didn't like it. But it stayed in the program as if I had never taken it out. For example, if I took out "What should I do?" and replaced it with "Hello world!" (just a random example) "What should I do?" would still appear. I checked my code over and I am sure that "What should I do?" and "Now what?" are not in it anywhere. I even deleted the `richTextBox1` and made it again. But the problem kept happening. I set a button to be clicked that hid `richTextBox1` and showed `richTextBox2` but it still happened. I am completely lost and would really like to get this text that shouldn't be there out of my game.

Comment: Did you "clean" the build environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you have a build error in there, and it is running an older build. It is probably not warning you about it, because you check the 'Do not show this dialog again', when it warned you about running with build errors.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, to compile all projects in the solution, and make sure you have no errors.

To have Visual Studio prompt about using older binaries, go to

**Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run->**

and on the

**On Run, when build or deployment errors occur** select **Prompt to launch**.

[image]

Comment: **Thank you so much** I did not know that it could run an older build. This solved my problem.